# Why vSGD-fd optimization algorithm isn't popular?

Tags: neural-network, optimization

As the [paper by Schaul & LeCun](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3764) states

> The findings are clear: in contrast to the other algorithms tested,
> vSGD-fd does not require any hyper-parameter tuning to give reliably
> good performance on the broad range of tests: the learning rates adapt
> automatically to different curvatures and noise levels.

Auto-adapting learning rate sounds like a huge deal,
but why is everyone seem to be using Adam and other optimizers?

Answer (score 1):

This is [my answer at Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/385571/161581) for the same question asked by the same person:

It's already 2019, still nobody answered this question. I don't understand why vSGD isn't popular either. But I do have some reasons from my own:

1. not real auto-adapting. Like v-SGD, ADAM is also a so-called auto-adapting algorithm, but that is not true. The learning rate, and window size in v-SGD, the \beta terms in ADAM all need tuning. The new-variants like [AMSGrad](https://openreview.net/forum?id=ryQu7f-RZ) and [NosAdam](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07557) seem to be more robust though.
2. too "complex". v-SGD uses a "bprop" term to estimate the Hessian diagonal,
   and later there is also a finite-difference version. These are somehow "complex" methods to use in computer science and engineering. The numerical instability and  the inherent inaccuracy can cause a lot of trouble. That may be the reason why Tensorflow and Pytorch developers didn't include v-SGD in their package. And that also caused very few comparisons with v-SGD in the subsequent optimization papers.
3. speed. If the estimated Hessian is a good approximate, then it surely speeds up. However, first, the local landscape may not be the "noisy quadratic loss" as stated in the paper; second, the estimate is also very rough. Actually, [there can be no exact estimate of Hessian diagonal](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6464). These factors all make the speed of v-SGD algorithm not so competitive.

That is only some understanding with not a lot of practice. Hope someone could point out probably more accurate points.